# Determine outbound https requests underlying TLS version

Tags: ssl, redhat

**Summary**

Is there a way to trace an outbound https request to verify TLS version with Red Hat / Unix. Something similar to Fiddler or Wireshark for Windows.

**Background**

I have a Java Application performing an outbound request to a third-party API that is failing with an SSL handshake error. I am unable to amend the call to Java so unable to use -djavax flags. Is there something I can trace with outside of the Java App? At OS level perhaps?

Everything on the server and application is configured to use TLS 1.2 but the third-party API is still rejecting the request.

My theory is that our outbound requests are still leaving the server under TLS 1.1 or we're going out on TLS 1.2 but with an unsupported cipher.

Thanks

Comment: Why not use Wireshark?

Comment: As suggested by @MichaelHampton, Wireshark works on Red Hat too, and if this is a remote headless server, you can perform a remote dump using `tcpdump` and piping to Wireshark.

Comment: A good question Michael. I should have elaborated - I was hoping there was something I could use on the OS already. I'm not a sysadmin nor do I have sudo access. If that's the best approach then I'll have to visit this with the necessary folks. I certainly appreciate the responses

Comment: Without root access the current packet capture approach is likely to fail. Can you configure the application connect to another server where you can log the protocol & cipher suites used? Or where you can capture the client hello.

Comment: @EsaJokinen - Thank you that is something I hadn't considered but would give us the visibility I'm after!

Comment: You don't have to have root to run Wireshark, your user just has to be in the `wireshark` group. It may be easier to get this access than to get sudo/root. You would need to be root to run `tcpdump`.